# PHP: Sending GET/POST with file_get_contents

Tags: php

I'm working on a new project. I route everything to router.php, but I have a problem now. I'm using `keywords`, so I can use:

> <[DEFAULT_JS]>

And the return is:

```
<script src="./assets/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This is the code:

```
// some code
if(in_array($_GET['p'], $allowedPages)) {
    $source = file_get_contents('./pages/'.$allowedPages[$_GET['p']]);      
    foreach($keywords as $key => $value) {
        $source = str_replace("<[".$key."]>", $value, $source);
    }

    echo $source;
} else {
// some code
```

You can see, I'm using file_get_contents to get the script and replace the 'keywords', but now it won`t send GET data with the page. When I use include it should work but then I cannot use the 'keywords' anymore.

So, how can include a file and replace the keywords?

Comment: "but now it won`t send GET data with the page" What?

Comment: Check what `'./pages/'.$allowedPages[$_GET['p']]` returns because it probably isn’t what you’re expecting.

Comment: The page than you open with file_get_contents() has php code?

Comment: @gabrieloliveira, yes.

Comment: with file_get_contents() you get the file content, not PHP is processed. Is this than you wish?

Comment: No, I need to process php.

Answer (score 0):

So basically you are inventing some template system and you want to use PHP in your templates?

I think that you can use eval() function for that. But it's still not a good option.

```
// some code
if(in_array($_GET['p'], $allowedPages)) {
    $source = file_get_contents('./pages/'.$allowedPages[$_GET['p']]);      
    foreach($keywords as $key => $value) {
        $source = str_replace("<[".$key."]>", $value, $source);
    }

    eval($source);
} else {
// some code
```

Comment: `eval()` is the devil and you shouldn't use it. There might be some exception for when it's okay to use `eval()`, but this is definitely not it. Just use `include()` or `require()`.